# Angular - Use a Barrel File for all Component Imports

Tags: angular, import, export, components

I am currently on Angular 5.

I have created a barrel file for all the common imports I use in my component files.  **The question that I have is - is this a good idea or bad idea in regards to lazy loading, tree shaking, or anything else I didn't think of such as AOT?**  Or is this approach completely fine and won't affect load time or anything else negatively.  If you could shine some light on the reason too that would be appreciated.

Examples:

```
  common-component-imports.ts:
    export { AppState, Event, EventPriority, EventType, Page, Unit, User, WindowSettings } from '../models/index';
    export { Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
    export { Config, IonicPage, Loading, LoadingController, Modal, ModalController, Nav, NavController, NavParams, Platform, Toast, ToastController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
etc../
```

and than in my components I am doing this:

```
event.ts
import {
  Component,
  ElectronService,
  Event,
  AppState,
  IonicPage,
  NavController,
  NavParams,
  Store,
 } from '../shared/common-component-imports';
```

and I import like that on several more files besides just event.ts.

Comment: No one has an idea/opinion?

Answer (score 4):

Barrels are a good idea in general but have no impact on lazy loading.
https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel (barrel has been removed from the glossary 2018)

UPDATE:
"Consider creating a "barrel" file that gathers all the interceptor providers into an httpInterceptorProviders array, starting with this first one, the NoopInterceptor." https://angular.io/guide/http

Style Guide" with NgModules (2016-09-27)
"StyleGuide explains recommended conventions for NgModules. Barrels now are far less useful and have been removed from the style guide; they remain valuable but are not a matter of Angular style. Also relaxed the rule that discouraged use of the @Component.host property." https://angular.io/guide/change-log

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a barrel definition in the docks anymore?

Comment: Apparently barrels are not recommended anymore. Source: https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/barrel-files-to-use-or-not-to-use-75521cd18e65